# linq default value if no records

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm making an auction I want to assign current price to starting price if no bids are placed. Here's my query. How could I do that?

```
var model = db.Items
            .Where(i => i.EndDate > DateTime.Now)
            .Select(i => new ViewItemViewModel
            {
                ItemId = i.ItemId,
                Title = i.Title,
                EndDate = i.EndDate,
                Description = i.Description,
                CurrentPrice = i.Bids.OrderByDescending(b => b.Price).First().Price
            }).ToList();
```

This is important part

```
CurrentPrice = i.Bids.OrderByDescending(b => b.Price).First().Price
```

Comment: ViewItemViewModel has CurrentPrice property design setter so that if its null , get some initial valuue

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to just use an inline if (you can just do this in linq)

```
CurrentPrice = i.Bids.Any() ? i.Bids.OrderByDescending(b => b.Price).First().Price : 27
```

**NOTE** if you are going back to a database (such as with EF) you probably want to use `FirstOrDefault()` instead as `First()` is not implemented in EF linq